# How to teach object oriented programming to procedural programmers?

Tags: oop

I have been asked to begin teaching C# and OO concepts to a group of procedural programmers. I've [searched for ideas](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS291US303&q=teach+oo&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g-p1g9) on where to begin, but am looking for general consensus on topics to lead with in addition to topics to initially avoid.

**Edit**

I intend to present information in 30 minute installments weekly until it no longer makes sense to meet. These presentations are targeted at coworkers at a variety of skill levels from novice to expert.

Comment: How much time do you have? What's the format? (classroom, at work, etc) And, are they generally skilled at what they do already?

Comment: @GreenReign Edited to address your questions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best thing you can do is: **Have *a ton* of Q&A**.

Wikipedia's [procedural programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) (PP) article really hits where you should start:

> Whereas procedural programming uses
>   procedures to operate on data
>   structures, object-oriented
>   programming bundles the two together
>   so an "object" operates on its "own"
>   data structure.

Once this is understood, I think a lot will fall into place.

**In general**

OOP is one of those things that can take time to "get," and each person takes their own path to get there. When writing in C#, it's not like the code screams, "**I am using OO principles!**" in every line. It's more of a subtle thing, like a `foreach` loop, or `string` concatenation.

**Design center**

Always *use* something (repeatedly) before *making* it.

First, *use* an object, and demonstrate the basic differences from PP. Like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> myList = new List<int>();

    myList.Add(1);
    myList.Add(7);
    myList.Add(5);

    myList.Sort();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myList[i]);
    }
}
```

*Using* objects (and other OO things) first -- before being forced to create their own -- leads people down the path of, "Ok, I'm making something like what I just used," rather than "WTF am I typing?"

**Inheritance (it's a trap!)**

I would NOT spend a lot of time on inheritance. I think it is a common pitfall for lessons to make a big deal about this (usually making a cliché animal hierarchy, as others pointed out). I think it's critical to *know about* inheritance, to understand *how to use* the .NET Framework, but its nuances aren't that big of a deal.

When I'm using .NET, I'm more likely to "run into inheritance" when I'm *using* the .NET Framework (i.e. "Does this control have a `Content` property?" or "I'll just call its `ToString()` method.") rather than when I'm creating my own class. Very (very (very)) rarely do I feel the need to make something mimicking the taxonomy structure of the animal kingdom.

**Interfaces**

Coding to an interface is a key mid-level concept. It's used everywhere, and OOP makes it easier. Examples of this are limitless. Building off the example I have above, one could demonstrate the `IComparer<int>` interface:

```
public int Compare(int x, int y)
{
    return y.CompareTo(x); 
}
```

Then, use it to change the sort order of the list, via `myList.Sort(this)`. (After talking about `this`, of course.)

**Best practices**

Since there are some experienced developers in the group, one strategy in the mid-level classes would be to show how various best practices work in C#. Like, information hiding, the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), etc.

**Have a ton of Q&A**

Again, everyone learns slightly differently. I think the best thing you can do is have a ton of Q&A and encourage others in the group to have a discussion. People generally learn more when they're involved, and you have a good situation where that should be easier.

Comment: The nested "very"'s gave me a good laugh. :)

Answer (score 12):

The leap from procedural to object oriented (even within a language - for four months I programmed procedural C++, and classes were uncomfortable for a while after) can be eased if you emphasize the more basic concepts that people don't emphasize.

For instance, when I first learned OOP, none of the books emphasized that each object has its own set of data members. I was trying to write classes for input validation and the like, not understanding that classes were to operate on data members, not input.

Get started with data structures right away. They make the OOP paradigm seem useful. People teach you how to make a "House" class, but since most beginning programmers want to do something useful right away, that seems like a useless detour.

Avoid polymorphism right away. Inheritance is alright, but teach when it is appropriate (instead of just adding to your base class).

Operator overloading is not essential when you are first learning, and the special ctors (default, dtor, copy ctor, and assignment operator all have their tricky aspects, and you might want to avoid that until they are grounded in basic class design).

Have them build a Stack or a Linked List. Don't do anything where traversal is tricky, like a binary tree.

Comment: Exactly. One of my first assignments was a very simple String class to replace C-Strings (don't fret, I use std::string :P). That taught new, delete, operator overloading, constructors, etc. I also designed a parser to take apart a string and return individual words, which is still useful.

Comment: Very well put... also pick small examples where there is an obvious advantage of OOP visible. Most of the times Language features are more taught, I would recommend spending more time on theory, design defects. If some one know procedural programming language features wont be a problem for him. Its the theory that needs time

Answer (score 8):

Do it in stages.

High level concepts : Describe what an object is and relate it to real life.

Medium level concepts: Now that they got what object is, try compare and contrast.  Show them why global variable is bad compared to an encapsulated value in a class. What advantage they might get from encapsulating.  Start introducing the tennets of OOP (encapsulation, inheritance)

Low Level concepts:  Go in further into polymorphism and abstraction.  Show them how they can gain even better design through polymorphism and abstraction.

Advance concepts: SOLID, Interface programming, OO design patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you should consider a problem that is work related and start with a procedural implementation of it and then work through (session by session) how to make an OOP implementation of it. I find professionals often grasp concepts better if it is directly related to real examples from their own work place. The junk examples most textbooks use are often horrible for understanding because they leave the student wondering, why on earth would I ever want to do that. Give them a real life reason why they would want to do that and it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid the "a bicycle is a kind of veichle" approach and try to apply OO to an environment that is fairly specific and that they are already used to. Try to find a domain of problems that they all recognize.

Excercise the basics in that domain, but try to move towards some "wow!" or "aha!" experience relatively early; I had an experience like that while reading about "*Replace Conditional with Polymorphism*" in Fowlers  [Refactoring](http://books.google.se/books?id=1MsETFPD3I0C&printsec=frontcover), that or similar books could be a good source of ideas. If I recall correctly, Michael Feathers [Working effectively with legacy code](http://books.google.se/books?id=cVrhAAAACAAJ&dq=working+effectively+with+legacy+code) contains a chapter about how to transform a procedural program into OO.

Answer (score 3):

**Teach Refactoring**

Teach the basics, the bare minimum of OO principles, then teach [Refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/) hands-on.

**Traditional Way: Abstractions > Jargon Cloud > Trivial Implementation > Practical Use** 
(Can you spot the disconnect here? One of these transitions is harder than the others.)

In my experience most traditional education does not do a good job in getting programmers to actually grok OO principles. Instead they learn a bit of the syntax, some jargon they have a vague understanding of, and a couple canonical design examples that serve as templates for a lot of what they do. This is light years from the sort of thorough understanding of OO design and engineering one would desire competent students to obtain. The result tends to be that code gets broken down into large chunks in what might best be described as object-libraries, and the code is nominally attached to objects and classes but is very, very far from optimal. It's exceedingly common, for example, to see several hundred line methods, which is not very OO at all.

**Provide Contrast To Sharpen The Focus on the Value of OO**

Teach students by giving them the tools up front to improve the OO design of existing code, through refactoring. Take a big swath of procedural code, use extract method a bunch of times using meaningful method names, determine groups of methods that share a commonality and port them off to their own class. Replace switch/cases with polymorphism. Etc. The advantages of this are many. It gives students experience in reading and working with existing code, a key skill. It gives a more thorough understanding of the details and advantages of OO design. It's difficult to appreciate the merits of a particular OO design pattern in vacuo, but comparing it to a more procedural style or a clumsier OO design puts those merits in sharp contrast.

**Build Knowledge Through Mental Models and Expressive Terminology**

The language and terminology of refactoring help students in understanding OO design, how to judge the quality of OO designs and implementations through the idea of code smells. It also provides students a framework with which to discuss OO concepts with their peers. Without the models and terminology of, say, an automobile transmission, mechanics would have a difficult time communicating with each other and understanding automobiles. The same applies to OO design and software engineering. Refactoring provides abundant terminology and mental models (design patterns, code smells and corresponding favored specific refactorings, etc.) for the components and techniques of software engineering.

**Build an Ethic of Craftsmanship**

By teaching students that design is not set in stone you bolster students' confidence in their ability to experiment, learn, and discover. By getting their hands dirty they'll feel more empowered in tackling software engineering problems. This confidence and practical skill will allow them to truly own the design of their work (because they will always have the skills and experience to change that design, if they desire). This ownership will hopefully help foster a sense of responsibility, pride, and craftsmanship.

Answer (score 2):

First, pick a language like C# or Java and have plenty of samples to demonstrate. Always show them the big picture or the big idea before getting into the finer details of OO concepts like abstraction or encapsulation. Be prepared to answer a lot of why questions with sufficient real world examples.

Answer (score 2):

Define an object first, not using some silly animal, shape, vehicle example, but with something they already know. The C stdio library and the `FILE` structure. It's used as an opaque data structure with defined functions. Map that from a procedural use to an OO usage and go from there to encapsulation, polymorphism, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kinda surprised there's any pure procedural programmers left ;-)

But, as someone who started coding back in the early 80s on procedural languages such as COBOL, C and FORTRAN, I remember the thing I had most difficulty with was instantiation.  The concept of an object itself wasn't that hard as basically they are 'structures with attached methods' (looked at from a procedural perspective) but handling how and when I instantiated an object - and in those days without garbage collection - destroyed them caused me some trouble.

I think this arises because in some sense a procedural programmer can generally point to any variable in his code any say that's where that item of data is directly stored, whereas as soon as you instantiated an object and assign values to that then it's much less directly tangible (using pointers and memory allocation in C is of course similar, which may be a useful starting point also if your students have C experience). In essence I suppose it means that your procedural -> OOPS programmer has to learn to handle another level of abstraction in their code, and getting comfortable with this mental step is more difficult than it appears.  By extension I'd therefore make sure that your students are completely comfortable with allocating and handling objects before looking at such potentially confusing concepts as static methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/) which has really nice and easy to understand examples of object oriented design which should really help. I wouldn't emphasize the 'patterns' aspect too much at this point though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a vb.net intermediate programmer, and I'm learning OOP. One of the things I find is the lecturing about the concepts over and over is unnerving. I think what would be perfect documentation would be a gradual transition from procedural programming to full blown OOP rather than trying to force them to understand the concepts then have them write exclusively OOP code using all the concepts. That way they can tinker with little projects like "hello world" without the intimidation of design.

For example (this is for VB.NET beginners not advanced procedural programmers).

I think the first chapters should always be about the general concepts, with just a few examples, but you should not force them to code strictly OOP right away, get them used to the language, so that it's natural for them. When I first started, I had to go back and read the manual over and over to remember HOW to write the code, but I had to wade through pages and pages of lecturing about concepts. Painful! 
I just need to remember how to create a ReadOnly Property, or something. What would be real handy would be a section of the book that is a language reference so you can easily look in there to find out HOW to write the code.

Then you briefly explaining how forms, and all the objects are already objects, that have methods, and show how they behave, and example code.

Then show them how to create a class, and have them create a class that has properties, and methods, and the new construct. Then have them basically switch from them using procedural code in the form or modules, to writing methods for classes.

Then you just introduce more advance codes as you would any programming language.
Show them how inheritance works, etc. Just keep expanding, and let them use thier creativity to discover what can be done.

After they get used to writing and using classes, then show how thier classes could improve, introducing the concepts one by one in the code, modifying the existing projects and making them better. One good idea is to take an example project in procedural code, and transform it into a better application in OOP showing them all the limitations of OOP.

Now after that is the advanced part where you get into some really advanced OOP concepts, so that folks who are familar with OOP already get some value out of the book.

Answer (score 1):

If they are good procedural programmers and know what a structure and a pointer to a function are, the hardest part of the job is already done!

I think a *low level* lecture about how Object Oriented Programming can be implemented in procedural languages, or even assembler, could be cool. Then they will appreciate the amount of work that the compiler does for them; and maybe they will find coding patterns that they already knew and have used previously.

Then, you can talk about best practices in good Object Oriented design and introduce a bit of UML.

And a very important thing to keep in mind always is that they're not freshmen, don't spend much time with basic things because they'll get bored.

Answer (score 1):

**Show Design Patterns in Examples**

There where some plenty good answers, alright. I also think, that you should use good languages, good, skillful examples, but I have an additional suggestion:

I have learned what OOP means, by studying Design Patterns. Of course, I have of course learned an OO-language before, but until I was working on Design Patterns, I did not understand the power of it all.

I also learned much from OO-Gurus like Robert C. Martin and his really great papers (to be found on his companies site).

Edit: I also advocate the use of UML (class diagrams) for teaching OO/Design-Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that made it click for me was introducing Refactoring and Unit Testing.  Most of my professional programming career has been in OO Languages, but I spent most of it writing procedural code.  You call a function on an instance of class X, and it called a different method on an instance of class Y.  I didn't see what the big deal about interfaces was, and thought that inheritance was simply a concept of convenience, and classes were by and large a way of helping us sort and categorize the massive code.  If one was masochistic enough, they could have easily go through some of my old projects and inline everything until you get to one massive class.  I'm still acutely embarrassed at how *bad* my code was, how naive my architecture was.

It half-clicked when we went through Martin Fowler's Refactoring book, and then fully clicked when started going through and writing Unit and Fitnesse tests for our code, forcing us to refactor.  Start pushing refactoring, dependency injection, and separation of the code into distinct MVC models.  Either it will sink in, or their heads will explode.

If someone truly doesn't get it, maybe they aren't cut out for working on OO, but I don't think anyone from our team got completely lost, so hopefully you'll have the same luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an OO developer professionally, but have had had procedural developers on my development team (they were developing Matlab code, so it worked). One of the concepts that I like in OO programming is how objects can relate to your domain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design - Eric Evans wrote a book on this, but it is not a beginner's book by any stretch).

With that said, I would start with showing OO concepts at a high level. Try to have them design a car for example. Most people would say a car has a body, engine, wheels, etc. Explain how those can relate to real world objects.

Once they seem to grasp that high level concept, then I would start in on the actual code part of it and concepts like inheritance vs aggregation, polymorphism, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I learned about OOP during my post-secondary education. They did a fairly good job of explaining the concepts, but completely failed in explaining why and when. They way they taught OOP was that absolutely everything had to be an object and procedural programming was evil for some reason. The examples they were giving us seemed overkill to me, partly because objects didn't seem like the right solution to every problem, and partly because it seemed like a lot of unnecessary overhead. It made me despise OOP.

In the years since then, I've grown to like OOP in situations where it makes sense to me. The best example I can think of this is the most recent web app I wrote. Initially it ran off a single database of its own, but during development I decided to have it hook into another database to import information about new users so that I could have the application set them up automatically (enter employee ID, retrieves name and department). Each database had a collection of functions that retrieved data, and they depended on a database connection. Also, I wanted an obvious distinction which database a function belonged to. To me, it made sense to create an object for each database. The constructors did the preliminary work of setting up the connections.

Within each object, things are pretty much procedural. For example, each class has a function called getEmployeeName() which returns a string. At this point I don't see a need to create an Employee object and retrieve the name as a property. An object might make more sense if I needed to retrieve several pieces of data about an employee, but for the small amount of stuff I needed it didn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Cost. Explain how when properly used the features of the language should allow software to be written and maintained for a lower cost. (e.g. Java's Foo.getBar() instead of the foo->bar so often seen in C/C++ code).
Otherwise why are we doing it?

Comment: That would imply bar is a public member, which it shouldn't be. C++ programmers should also be using foo.getBar(). Getter and setter functions are commonly used in C++ as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the book [Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=10142) to be very helpful in understanding and giving me a vocabulary to discuss the differences in language paradigms. The book doesn't really cover Java or C# as 00-languages, but rather the concepts of different paradigms. If i was teaching OO i would start by showing the differences in the paradigms, then slowly the differences in the 00-languages, the practical stuff they can pickup by themselves doing coursework/projects.

Answer (score 0):

When I moved from procedural to object oriented, the first thing I did was get familiarized with static scope.

Java is a good language to start doing OO in because it attempts to stay true to all the different OO paradigms.

A procedural programmer will look for things like program entry and exit points and once they can conceptualize that static scope on a throwaway class is the most familiar thing to them, the knowledge will blossom out from there.

I remember the lightbulb moment quite vividly.  Help them understand the key terms abstract, instance, static, methods and you're probably going to give them the tools to learn better moving forward.